# Writing a SPARQL query with Jena, FILTER and REGEX

Tags: java, regex, string, sparql, jena

I wrote I `SPARQL` query with `JENA` with the `REGEX`: `/^name$/i`  (Actually `name` is a String variable that could be any value, with spaces or not, it's received as a parameter of the method).

Here's the String query:

```
String authorquery = "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> " +
                "PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> " +
                "PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> SELECT " +
                "?URIAutor WHERE { " +
                "?URIAutor foaf:name ?Autor." + 
                "FILTER (regex(?Autor, \"" + "/^" + name + "$/" + "\", 'i' )  ).}";
```

That isn't giving me an exception, but isn't returning me results when I write a name that I'm sure is on the Database.
That's what I want with this query: I have the name "Agatha Christie" on the database. If `name=Agatha` I would like the query to return nothing. I'd like it only to return me the URI from the author named "Agatha Christie" if name="Agatha Christie"(can be case insentive). The same holds for the names "Bill Clinton" and "Bill Gates", if `name=Bill` I wouldn't like to find both URIs, but the query should return no results. The result should come for "Bill Clinton" only if `name="Bill Clinton"`.

I don't know if the problem is with the REGEX or with turning the REGEX into a String with a variable in the middle.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put `/.../` around the regex string.  `^name$` will do.